How to retrieve full tweets using ScraperAPI for sentiment analysis?
I need help with scraping data from Twitter using ScraperAPI for my project on sentiment analysis of electric vehicles. I requested 10 tweets and managed to get the tweets using the code below. However, the tweets(snippet) in the output are truncated. Is there a way to get the entire tweet?
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you!
Here's the code I used:
import requests
import pandas as pd

twitter_data = []  

payload = {
    'api_key': ' ',  # I inserted my API key here
    'query': 'electric vehicle',
    'num': '10'
}

response = requests.get('https://api.scraperapi.com/structured/twitter/search', params=payload)
data = response.json()
print(data)

OUTPUT: # I have removed two headers from each section of the output that highlight links.
{
    "search_information": {"query_displayed": "site:twitter.com \"electric vehicle\""},
    "organic_results": [
        {
            "position": 0,
            "title": "Felix Hamer • electricfelix",
            "snippet": "The Slowdown in US Electric Vehicle Sales Looks More Like a Blip by @tsrandall \"And for all the talk of an EV slowdown, many longer-term...",
            "highlights": ["Electric Vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 1,
            "title": "energy star - X.com",
            "snippet": "Making the switch to an electric vehicle is not only good for the planet, it could also save you $1400/year on fuel and car maintenance.",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 2,
            "title": "Electric Vehicle Association (@ev_association) / X",
            "snippet": "We are a network of Electric Vehicle advocates, 100% volunteer led, and represent over 100 chapters and thousands of members across North America. Automotive",
            "highlights": ["Electric Vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 3,
            "title": "US Department of Energy",
            "snippet": "HOP IN! New electric vehicle charging stations are popping up everywhere, making it easier than ever to power up and ride.",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 4,
            "title": "Big_Orrin",
            "snippet": "So electric vehicle operating costs continue to use vs ICEs. Price paid per mile the same as ICE cars but ICE cars see their fuel prices...",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 5,
            "title": "Is the Electric Cars Revolution Losing Momentum?",
            "snippet": "An electric vehicle is probably only suitable for individuals who have a designated area for charging at their homes. Globally, China has...",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 6,
            "title": "Chase Cain",
            "snippet": "Electric vehicle charging isn't keeping up, frustrating EV drivers ⚡️ according to new report from. @JDPowerAutos.",
            "highlights": ["Electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 7,
            "title": "Route Fifty",
            "snippet": "People who live closer to public electric vehicle chargers view the cars more positively, even when accounting for people's party...",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 8,
            "title": "nyserda",
            "snippet": "Sunday Read: Electric vehicle fast chargers are growing strongly in the United States with one EV fast charging station for every 15 gas...",
            "highlights": ["Electric vehicle"]
        },
        {
            "position": 9,
            "title": "ICF",
            "snippet": "The electric vehicle market in the U.S. is growing rapidly, yet EVs are still considered inaccessible to many due to their high upfront cost.",
            "highlights": ["electric vehicle"]
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "load_more_url": "http://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dsite%3Atwitter.com%2B%2522electric%2Bvehicle%2522%26sca_esv%3Da24d50f4328fb081%26gl%3DUS%26ei%3DUDBXZpXaONK9kPIP_6eTSA%26start%3D10%26sa%3DN&autoparse=true",
        "pages_count": 1
    }
}

